# Clear last file input onclick

Tags: jquery, file-upload, input

I have a form with a file input and 2 text boxes. All 3 inputs can be duplicated if more than one file needs to be uploaded. I am trying to add a clear button at the end of every div that will allow the user to clear the value of the file input. But for the life of me I cannot get it to work.

I am trying to use `.last()` but it doesn't seem to be selecting the last file input once the div has been duplicated.

My code is below.

```
<div class="certificates_list">
    <input type="file" name="user_certificates[]" class="user_certificate" />
    <input type="text" name="certificate_name[]" class="right certificate_name" placeholder="Certificate name" />
    <input type="text" name="expiry_date[]" class="expiry_date" placeholder="DD/MM/YYYY" />
    <button class="clear_certificate">Clear</button>
</div>

$(function() {
    $('.clear_certificate').click(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $('input[type="file"].user_certificate').last().val('');

    });
});
```

If I just have one div with inputs it clears it fine. Once the div has been duplicated the previous div won't clear anymore.

Any ideas? Thank you for any help, much appreciated!

EDIT

I have created a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/bea68/2/) with my problem, hope this helps

Comment: What are you duplicating exactly? Sounds like you need to use [`.on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) instead of `.click()` for the event, because it only registers what's already loaded in the DOM and not future elements.

Comment: what do you mean by row?

Comment: I meant div, it is styled as a row on my screen. My bad. Updated my question

Comment: I'm duplicating all 3 inputs

Comment: Look a example https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml5_input_type_reset

Comment: This is almost 4 years old and i have already accepted an answer....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HTML-CODE:

```
<div class="certificates_list">
    <input type="file" name="user_certificates[]" class="user_certificate" id="user_certificate_0" />
    <input type="text" name="certificate_name[]" class="right certificate_name" placeholder="Certificate name" id="certificate_name_0" />
    <input type="text" name="expiry_date[]" class="expiry_date" id="expiry_date_0" placeholder="DD/MM/YYYY" />
    <button id="clear_certificate_0" class="clear_certificate">Clear</button>
</div>
<div id="certificates_new"></div>
<p><button type="button" id="add_certificate">Add another certificate</button></p>
```

JS:

```
var i = 1;

$('#add_certificate').click(function(){
    var sHtml = '<input type="file" name="user_certificates[]" class="user_certificate" id="user_certificate_'+i+'" />';
    sHtml +=    '<input type="text" name="certificate_name[]" class="right certificate_name" placeholder="Certificate name" id="certificate_name_'+i+'" />';
    sHtml +=    '<input type="text" name="expiry_date[]" class="expiry_date" placeholder="DD/MM/YYYY" id="expiry_date_'+i+'" />';
    sHtml +=    '<button class="clear_certificate" id="clear_certificate_'+i+'">Clear</button>';
    $('#certificates_new').append(sHtml);
    i++;
});

$(document).on("click", '.clear_certificate', function() {
    var arrID = $(this).attr("id").split("_");
    var ID = arrID[2];
    $('#user_certificate_'+ID).val('');
    $('#expiry_date_'+ID).val('');
    $('#certificate_name_'+ID).val('');
});
```

So now this should work fine... You should make improvements on the code to shorten it a bit but the functionality is given.

Comment: Are you using the latest jQuery version? Or getting any error?

Comment: Yup the latest version, and no i'm not getting any errors at all

Comment: And would it be an option to set up a counter (var i = 1) and add an id (i.e. "user_certificate_"+i) to every added input field so you can select the latest by its id? Know what I try to say? :)

Comment: And proof wether the onclick function gets called. Maybe it never gets called

Comment: Updated my question with a jsfiddle

Comment: Updated my answer - hope I got it now :) Here's the Fiddle-URL: http://jsfiddle.net/bea68/3/

Comment: YOU HERO! It worked, I did need to fiddle around with the code a little bit, but it works perfectly regardless. +1 for you, cheers!

Answer (score 0):

you write [type="file"]  only match type="file" 
your html only have one file input

Comment: As I said in my question the inputs get duplicated when a button is clicked. I didn't include it in my question as I didn't think it was relevant

Answer (score 0):

This should accomplish what you are trying to do:

```
$(".clear_certificate").click(function(){
   $(".certificates_list").children("input[type=file]:last-child").each(function(){
         // Do stuff here
   });
});
```

It would be best to give your wrapper div an id and then do $("#idOfDiv").children....

Comment: Updated my question with a jsfiddle